# Get an error while dumping database in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
D:\>mysqldump -uuser -ppass dbname > 1.dump.sql.txt
mysqldump: Got error: 1146: Table 'dbname.admin20_cache' doesn't exist when using LOCK TABLES
```

How to make MySQL ignore the error ?

Comment: did you try to create table named 'admin20_cache' ?

Comment: No,I want it to ignore errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--ignore-table=name Do not dump the specified table. To specify more than one
                      table to ignore, use the directive multiple times, once
                      for each table.  Each table must be specified with both
                      database and table names, e.g.
                      --ignore-table=database.table

I think this might be your only option (from `mysqldump --help`)